# How to shift user in ubuntu using ssh keypair

Tags: ssh, login, aws

In aws EC2,
I login to `ubuntu` user with ssh keypair:

```
ssh ubuntu@hostname -i path_to_the_keypair
```

Now, I want to shift to root user
so I try to login to root user by entering

```
$ su root
```

and it asks for password how to enter ssh password.

Is there any way to change the user using ssh keypair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't authenticate `su` using your keypair. But you will probably have configured `sudo` and you can "change to `root` user" using `sudo -i`.